# Console error accessing webcam HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, webcam

I've got a problem testing my webcam in HTML5.

That's the code:

```
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Display Webcam Stream</title>
   <script language="Javascript">
        var video = document.getElementById('video');

        if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
             navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true 
                  }).then(function(stream) {
                  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                  video.play();
             });
        }
   </script>
```

inside the body there is:

```
<video id="video" autoplay="true"></video>
```

Going to the website (HTTPS) it ask me the permission for webcam, after I allow it my webcam turn on but looking at the console appairs an error:

```
testing.php:14 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
at testing.php:14
at <anonymous>
```

How can I solve it?

(Sorry for bad english)

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like your JS is executed before the element exists on the page. Try moving your code to the end of the page before the closing body tag

Answer (score 0):

There is no element with id `video`

Also if there were, `getElementById` would still return `null`. You need to move the script at the end of the page or inside a `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Comment: I forgot to write the id inside video tag inside the question but php page always got the error.